# FindFit and log norm function

Tags: fitting, data

I'm trying to fit a function to data using `FindFit`, but I can't find a way to replace norm function RMSE with a RMSE in log space: `Total[(Log10[a] - Log10[b])^2]`

I tried:

```
logNorm [x_, y_] = Total[(Log10[x + 1] - Log10[y + 1])^2];
nlm = FindFit[data, x*a+b, {a, b}, x, NormFunction -> (logNorm[#] &)]
```

But I get an error:

> The function value `logNorm[<long list>]` is not a real number at `{a,b} = {1.,1.}`.

Comment: `NormFunction` operates on the list of residuals, which are already formed and provided to this function. You seem to want it to represent the log-distance to the point. Sorry, but it cannot do this; you should use `FindMinimum` instead with a suitable objective function. `FindFit` just calls `FindMinimum` internally, if that makes you feel better.

Comment: But, perhaps I misunderstood your question. Is `Norm[Log10[## + 1], 2] &` what you want? I am not sure I understand what your `x` and `y` arguments to `logNorm` are supposed to represent.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to replace RMSE with LRMSE. If residuals are already formed, then it's not possible and I'd have to use FindMinimum. In logNorm, x corresponds to observed value and y to fitted value provided by a model. In other words I wanted to replace current residuals calculated as "x-y" with "Log10[x+1]-Log10[y+1]".

Comment: @Krzysztof Narkowicz, I guess the norm-function should be represented as `f[Delta=observed-calculated]`, so you should transform your logarithmic expression to this form instead of your `f[observed,calculated]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your *data* to the `NormFunction`:

```
myNorm[residuals_, data_] := 
   Total[(Log[data[[All, 2]] + 1] - 
          Log[data[[All, 2]] + residuals + 1])^2];
data = {#, 2 # + 10 + # RandomReal[{0, 2}]} & /@ Range[100];
fit = x*a + b /. 
    FindFit[data, x*a + b, {a, b}, x, 
         NormFunction -> (myNorm[#, data] &)]
```

> 10.3158 + 2.86435 x

```
Show[{ListPlot[data], Plot[fit, {x, 0, 100}]}]
```

[image]

or even do this: `NormFunction -> (logNorm[data[[All, 2]] + #, data[[All, 2]]] &)` and your function as originally defined will work.