# How to get statistics of FindFit with changed norm-function?

Tags: fitting

I changed the norm-function of `FindFit` according to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102518/findfit-and-log-norm-function), because apparently it is not supported for `NonlinearModelFit` that has inbuilt statistic analysis ([see also this question)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61340/what-is-the-difference-between-findfit-and-nonlinearmodelfit).

Now, is there a way to easily obtain statistics on the fit of `FindFit`, like standard error, rsquared, adj rsquared? Are there predefined commands that could do this?

Comment: Check `VarianceEstimatorFunction` option of `NonLinearModelFit`. `FindFit` probably doesn't have any inbuilt statistics yielding method